# Adding lines to JSON didnt work on other server

Tags: php, json

i have a small problem with my PHP and JSON. All the stuff works fine on my testing server but not on my real server.

the problem is that my POST will not be saved at my comment.json...

Here is my AJAX

```
function sendContentToFile(id, name){   

    var idB, nameB, d, tag, stunden, minuten, month, monat,datum, content;
    d = new Date();
    tag = d.getDate();
    stunden = d.getHours();
    minuten = d.getMinutes();
    month = new Array();
    month[0] = "Januar";
    month[1] = "Februar";
    month[2] = "März";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "Mai";
    month[5] = "Juni";
    month[6] = "Juli";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "Oktober";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "Dezember";
    monat = month[d.getMonth()];
    if(minuten <= 9)  {
        minuten = 0+ d.getMinutes();
    } 
    datum = tag + ". " + monat + " , "+ stunden + ":" + minuten;
    idB = id;
    nameB = name;
    content = document.getElementById("textarea"+nameB+'0'+idB).value;
    console.log(content);
var url = "comments.php";

var neuesObject = {"Name" : nameB, "id" : idB, "comment" : content,"datum" : datum  };
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open('POST', url, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
           if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

                window.location.reload();
                }
            };
if (content!= "") {             
http.send('id='+idB+'&name='+nameB+'&comment='+content+'&datum='+datum);
 } else {
alert('Einfügen');
}
}
```

And my PHP File

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$datum = $_POST["datum"];
$AdditionalArray = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'comment' => $comment,
            'datum' => $datum
            );



            //open or read json data
            $data_results = file_get_contents('comments.json');

            $tempArray = json_decode($data_results);
            //append additional json to json file
            $tempArray[]=$AdditionalArray;
            $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);

        file_put_contents('comments.json', $jsonData);
```

does somebody know whats wrong with this kind of stuff?

Comment: It could be 1000 different reasons; have you tried to debug it?

My rough guess is file permissions, but can't know for sure without debugging.
Turn error reporting on and test it again

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. If you are running it on server check your folder permission is it 777 so that you can able to save your comments.json file in it.